# Controlling symbol visibility iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sdk, static-libraries

I'm developing a sdk which uses a third party library say "X".

What will happen if the app which integrates with my sdk uses "X"(same version or different version) for their purpose?

Will there be any linking issue with "X" between the sdk and the app?

Is there a way to set the visibility of "x" only within our sdk?

The main problem here is , my sdk should not interfere with app's usage of "x".

Comment: To the first question, you will get duplicate symbol error when linking. Solution maybe remove "X" in the app.

Comment: @KudoCC: I cant remove "x" from app.Then it makes my sdk to be inefficient.My sdk should not interfere with app's usage.

Comment: I also want the solution to archive that.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, as you are developing for iOS, all these libraries/SDKs are static-libraries.

You will only encounter an issue if a different version of "X" is used *and* the API has changed (i.e. the semantics of method calls, or other changes).

If the same version of "X" is used, the app and your SDK will be linked together, with "X", and both will happily use the single instance of "X" that is linked in with the app.

Comment: What if the "x" is compiled within the sdk.ie,including all the classes of "x" within my sdk target.This won't interfere with ap right?

Comment: @Karthik207 If your SDK is a static-library then "X" cannot be "compiled into it".

Comment: its a static frameowrk.

Comment: @Karthik207 But that's ultimately a static-library, isn't it.  Static-libraries are just an archive of object files, and will not contain code from any other static-library they reference, until they are finally linked with the binary executable.